# Java pstmt sqlUpdate accessed by index

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement

I am trying to update the db with sql prepared statement but the issue is that the parameters are accessed by index. I am trying to do the following:

```
String sql = 
"UPDATE table1
SET par1 = ?,
SET par2 = ?,
SET par3 = ?,

WHERE par4 =?"
```

BUT the problem is I am adding a column and it is mapped to par5. How can I also set this parameter within this sql statement?

Comment: I am not sure if I am getting it correctly, are you saying that you can't change the sql string to add , SET par5=? and update the java?

Comment: This is not PL/SQL, just plain SQL.   Please show ALL relevent code.  The question, as currently written, is not sufficient.  Please read [ask].

Comment: Your SQL statement in syntactically wrong. Please study some SQL basics first.

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql = "UPDATE table1 SET par1 = ?, par2 = ?, par3 = ?,WHERE par4 =?"
```

Comment: This is an improvement, but you still left the extra comma before the WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
String sql = "UPDATE table1 SET par1 = ?, par2 = ?, par3 = ?, par5 = ? WHERE par4 =?"
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1, par1);
pstmt.setString(2, par2);
pstmt.setString(3, par3);
pstmt.setString(4, par5);
pstmt.setString(5, par4);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```